Supported Kubernetes Versions for Each Kubernetes Client JAR Version
One of our spark containers uses a jar called "kubernetes-client-4.12.0.jar". Is there a document available mentioning its respective Kubernetes version support. Currently we have Kubernetes version 1.29 and need to know whether this particular jar is supported.
I checked maven repository for the jar version kubernetes-client but couldn't find a supported Kubernetes version details.

There might be a answer to this in the Github issues or if you dive into the code, but if you're looking for a document specifically, no. There was a compatibility matrix in https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/v4.12.0/README.md#compatibility-matrix but it doesn't have information for Kubernetes versions past 1.18.0.
If you're wondering why they stopped maintaining the matrix table, "Starting from v5.5, the Kubernetes Client should be compatible with any supported Kubernetes cluster version"
Edit: If you look at https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blame/4d0afa20e011fff89c6ca52a9be39a4694141518/README.md they have more information. kubernetes-client 4.12.0 is listed as being fully compatible with up to 1.18, partially compatible with up to 1.22.1, and no compatibility after that.
Note "officially compatible" and "working" are two different things, so if you get lucky maybe it would still work with a newer Kubernetes version.

I appreciate your detailed answer. However, the issues started to pop-up from last two day, and developers are mentioning about version compatibility and that's how I came here. Though I upgraded to 1.29 last week, I just want to make sure the versions are perfect.
